# Still no Intellisense in MVC5 .cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

I see a lot of posts on this topic - no Intellisense in VS Express 2013 for Web .cshtml files. I see that some people are having success after installing the 2013.1 update, but that didn't work for me.

It didn't just quit working - it hasn't ever worked in VS Express 2013 for me. Every line that begins with `@` is just a black line. No highlighting, no Intellisense while typing.

I've installed the 2013.1 update.

Launched vwdexpress.exe /resetsettings

Checked the AppSettings section in web.config:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

Are there any other possible solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

Those web.config settings look ok.

As its never worked looks as though something is broken so a reinstall would be best (but painful). But first there is a 2nd update for visual studio 2013 available [VS2013.2](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/aspnet-and-web-tools-20132-preview-for-visual-studio-2013-release-notes) this may correct the problem although as the first update didn't it is unlikely, worth a try. Good luck.

Comment: I updated, but you're right - it made no difference. I've read quite a few posts that even reinstalling hasn't helped quite a few. This problem sucks. I'm just learning razor and without highlighting and Intellisense it makes it tough.

Comment: I had something similar when on vs2010 which also refused to update sometime back and had to bite the bullet and reinstall by first removing vs (repairing was failing too), it was ok after that -deepjoy - one thing though check what else you have as it may effect side by side installs of other versions. And as its express may be better after you removed old one download newer version which may include the update)

Comment: Since updating I am now having other issues. Good old MS...  Wants me to disable the schema consistency check for ASP.NET Identity by setting throwIfV1Schema = false in the constructor of my ApplicationDbContext, yet making that setting throws an error: `The name 'throwIfV1Schema' does not exist in the current context`' I also see that the IdentityUser has UserName changed to Email which I already did in my project and now there is a conflict... I'm not sure how to get out of this problem.

Comment: Oh I think that the asp.net identity 1.0 -> 2.0 issue which arises if a db was created under v1, EF issue fix was to Enable-Migrations and adding Add-Migration update1 to fix the schema issue - probably worth doing some research. All consequence of rapid 'cadence'

Comment: I posted a new question on this with all of the pertaining information. MS makes it difficult to be productive at times. Sometimes updates fix problems, many times they detonate a stick of TNT on my desk and it takes precious time away from me just so I can get back to work. :S