# No IntelliSense for C# code in CSHTML files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, autocomplete, intellisense

I am using **VS 2013 MVC 5 ASP.NET**

I am brand new in **MVC 5 ASP.Net**. I wanted to code in my **CSHTML** files like

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()
```

But there is no Autocomplete, no IntelliSense for this function, no parameter and hint is shown. I have searched a lot but I am not getting a solution for this problem. I am just getting IntelliSense for HTML tags in my CSHTML file, but nothing for this C# codes. But in the videos about VS 2013 MVC I realized that there must exist IntelliSense, Autocomplete and parameter hints for this functions.

What I have done:

1. I have deleted the .suo file and restarted VS Studio
2. I have even repaired the whole VS 2013
3. I uninstalled Xamarin Extension.
4. I reseted all the options
5. I have tried to use the solutions of the following threads:

   - [IntelliSense won't work for MVC Razor cshtml page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481477/intellisense-wont-work-for-mvc-razor-cshtml-page)
   - [Still no Intellisense in MVC5 .cshtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24277420/still-no-intellisense-in-mvc5-cshtml)
   - [Visual studio 2013 intellisense stops working for ASP.NET MVC5 Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21471887/visual-studio-2013-intellisense-stops-working-for-asp-net-mvc5-controllers)

But the problem still remains
How can I enable that for my view files (CSHTML)?

Comment: Would you please include your Windows version, Visual Studio version, .NET being used and so on? Also where you got them?

Comment: if possible try to install resharper it is a great tool for development

Comment: I am using Windows 7, VS Studio 2013 Prof Version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4, .Net 4.5.50938 (German Version). I have bought the VS from Amazon and it is totally legal.

Comment: Does your c# code get highlighted with a colour scheme (i.e. the IDE is recognising it as c#) like this site has done for your snippet above?

Comment: @scgough In the cshtml files no. It doesn't get highlighted with a colour scheme

Comment: OK, I would confirm that MVC is actually correctly installed on the machine running VS and there are no issues with updates awaiting to be installed.Check 'Tools > Extensions & Updates...' in VS as well as 'Install Web Components'. I think you can install MVC 5 via Nuget: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/5.2.3

Comment: @scgough I have run this command and it shows that "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.3"  is already installed

Comment: Very strange @MoProg ! I'm afraid I can't offer any more advice but will come back to the thread if anything springs to mind. Hope you get it sorted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intellisense in razor files (.cshtml) not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309817/intellisense-in-razor-files-cshtml-not-work)

Answer (score 0):

I copped with the same issue. I have fixed it by downloading the Microsoft Web Tools for VS 2013_1 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=41532)! and run it. It should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Well,it happens sometime.

Usually,If restarting the VS or restarting the computer could not solve this problem,I would  chose to repair the VS.